# Mixed Arabic + English formatted date needs to be translated to all English in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr

I have a Python 3 script that detects Arabic text. I can detect the text and translate it correct for the most part.

The issue enters in when I have a mixed Arabic + English formatted date string.

I tried using this code to translate it to all English:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from datetime import datetime

result = datetime.strptime(unidecode('٦‏/١١‏/٢٠١٨ ٨:١٢ م').replace('S', 'A').replace('m', 'P') + 'M', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

This fails however as the date is formatted like this:

> ماي9 05

where is ماي9 = "May".

How can I translate this correctly to English?

Comment: do you mean it works when all the numbers are in arabic? or even if the numbers are in arabic it returns arabic letters and english numbers?

Comment: @Ta946 it has trouble with mixed English & Arabic. It also prints the Arabic text backwards (left to right instead of right to left).

Comment: sorry I'm still not sure what you mean by it has trouble with mixed. can you add more examples to the question of the input when it works and when it fails?